# "en" versus "je": What's the difference?

Tags: word-choice

The following sentence came from Duolingo.

> Lia kuzo alvenis **je** la deka.
>
> *His cousin arrived on the tenth.*

Both *en* and *je* mean *on*. (The former was not one of the choices.) When should I use *en* or *je*? Is it also correct to use *en* instead of *je* in the above sentence?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Je* is an abstract preposition. One of its frequent uses is for times and dates:

> *Tio okazos je la deka horo.* That will happen at ten o' clock.
>
> *Tio okazos je la deka de Oktobro.* That will happen on the tenth of October.

Notice that *dum* and *en* won't work for "o' clock", as *dum la unua horo* means "during the first hour", i.e. *before* one o' clock. In contrast, there is no problem with saying *dum/en la deka de Oktobro*.

Therefore, in the absence of a noun (and without context clues) I would interpret *je la deka* as "at ten o' clock" rather than "on the tenth".

> *Tio okazos je la deka.* That will happen at ten.
>
> *Tio okazos la dekan.* That will happen on the tenth.

It is conventional to keep the accusative for numbered days if there is no noun. Be aware however that these are conventions rather than rules. You may also encounter *sur* or *ĉe* for either.